# PHP: How to return original file name when downloading?

Tags: php

I'm uploading a file to a server then I store the original file name in a database.

Now for downloading I am currently using something like this:

`Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename=<?=urlencode($file)?>`

It works but it replaces space characters with +

How can I restore the original filename when downloading?

Comment: the `urlencode` function is encoding your string - dont encode it !?!

Comment: @ManseUK If I don't it breaks when there's a space character.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment There's no need to `urldencode` on receipt, the only reason I use `urlencode` is because it breaks when there's spaces. Now I realize I just need to put quotes so I don't need to use `urlencode` or `urldecode` anymore.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Yup that's how it's implemented, I only encountered the problem when I started downloading using user-friendly name which in my case was the original filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `urlencode` function is putting the `+` signs in your filename string - if you dont want the `+` signs remove the `urlencode` - then put the string in quotes :

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
```